# CSS Selector Across Multiple Classes

Tags: html, css

Say I have a rule like this:

```
.classA, .classB, li, .classC :nth-child(2) {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

This will apply the margin-top rule to all of these classes and items. However, suppose I want to use a selector and apply the rule to all but the first element that matches the above rule. For example, if I have:

```
<div class="classA"></div>
<div class="classB"></div>
<div class="classC">
    <ol>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

I would like for the rule to only apply to class B and the two list items, but not class A, which is the first element of the listed types, and not ol, which is not in the listed types at all. Is there a way to apply the not:first-child selector to a list of classes rather than just a single class?

As another example:

```
<div class="classB"></div>
<div class="notInList"></div>
<div class="classA"></div>
```

should only apply the rule to the third div, classA, and NOT the first (because it is the first matching the list specified) or second div (because it is not in the list).

Comment: break the rule into two separate rules, maybe?

Comment: So you want these divs to all have a margin-top except the `:first-child`?

Comment: Have you tried to remove `.classA` from selectors list?

Comment: Suppose classA could come in a different order, or not at all. It can't be removed from the list.

Comment: I want the divs to have a margin-top except the first, as well as the list items. In other words, it should apply across multiple types of elements that I specify.

Comment: Not the first selector from the list or not `.classA` itself? Have you tried `:not(.classA)`?

Comment: I want the rule to apply to all but the first of ANY and ALL of the types specified. In other words, if classB comes before classA in the snippet I posted, the rule should be applied to classA, classC, and the two list items.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful input. Care to explain why this is ridiculous? I would rather not split this up in to a bunch of rules that capture all the different possible combinations (.classA + .classB, .classB + .classA, etc.). Permuting it would explode the amount of code necessary.

Comment: @David I know this isn't exactly an answer, but if you used nested styles in SASS, you would at least not need to manage that code explosion by hand.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister, supposing I have access to SASS, how could I achieve the desired result?

Comment: The Sass tag was removed for a reason, do not add back in irrelevant tags.

Comment: @cimmanon How is it irrelevant? Someone just mentioned that this can be solved with SASS. I have access to SASS so why remove it?

Comment: Sass only compiles to CSS, meaning you have to know what CSS you need to write to meet your objective.

Comment: @cimmanon I don't understand your logic. SASS adds features on top of CSS, even if it's compiled down to CSS. For example, if SASS has the ability to permute combinations, my issue can be solved in a relatively small amount of SASS code even if it would take a ton of CSS. It's simple to solve my problem using just CSS in an inefficient way (as mentioned earlier by permuting the different possible element combinations), but if SASS can provide an elegant solution, it should be acceptable.

Comment: But the problem here is that you *don't know what CSS you need* in the first place.

Comment: You just restated what you said earlier without clarifying my misunderstanding. I can write CSS code that solves my problem, but it will require a lot of code, so I do know what CSS I need. Someone said earlier that nested styles in SASS can manage the complexity of this solution, so SASS seems pretty appropriate here.

Comment: Am I completely missing something here? Everyone seems to speak of the ':first-child' selector as if it was some magical ':first-match' selector - which it is *not*, it only refers to the elements position within its closest parent...? No matter how much css or sass you are willing to write I don't see this happening without turning to javascript, css simply isn't capable of knowing if some element earlier in the flow (that may not even share the same parent) already matched the rule (or exception).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to apply the not:first-child selector to a list of classes rather than just a single class?

No.

The way to do this is to give everything in your group a common class:

```css
div {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 2px;
}
.classA, .classB, .classC {
    background-color: blue;
}
.fun-times:not(:first-child) { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA fun-times"></div>
<div class="classB fun-times"></div>
<div class="classC fun-times"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It could do the trick

```
div:not(:first-child) { 
   background-color: red
}
```

Comment: The issue is that this must work across multiple types of elements. In the example above, the rule is applied to the list items as well as the divs. Also, it is only applied to divs of a certain class, not all divs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reference the parent element of the list:

```
.collection > :not(:first-child) {
     background-color: aqua;
 }

<div class="collection">
    <div class="classB">a</div>
    <div class="notInList">b</div>
    <div class="classA">c</div>
</div>
```

If you're really only looking to select the wildcard first element in a div, you can do just that, whether they have no classes, or are different elements like a span or div.  We are using the > operator that selects only direct children.  You can wildcard pseudo elements like this:

```
.collection > :first-child {
     background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: This will only handle the case where the class that's not in the list is explicitly named .notInList. It may be named something else. It may also not have a class.

Also, this won't handle the first code snippet, which has list items which need to be applied and are contained within an ordered list.